# Failing to run Rake-Task in Textmate

Tags: ruby, textmate

I'm starting to write Ruby code for Chef using Textmate 1.5.11, and need some help with an error i'm getting when attempting to run tasks from a RakeFile.

When I try to run Bundles->Ruby->rake->run rake task, I'm expecting to be prompted for which task i'd like to run from my rakefile. Instead, I'm getting the following error:

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- run_rake_task (LoadError) from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require' from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Ruby.tmbundle/Support/RakeMate/rake_mate.rb:7:in `'

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [Textmate + RVM + Rake = Rake not using expected gem environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770969/textmate-rvm-rake-rake-not-using-expected-gem-environment) for some answers about this particular problem, and some advice on how to diagnose your own situation.